# Are there any programmable barcode scanners that can call a webservice?

Tags: barcode-scanner

I am looking at integrating a C# application with a barcode scanner.

The last time I did this was with Delphi 1  (win 3.11) using a scanner that plugged in-line into the keyboard cable.

Looking around it appears most scanners are USB based these days and assume they emulate keyboard entry.

Anybody know of more sophisticated/programmable scanner that can call a webservice or even just do a basic POST/GET this would eliminate the C# application and the computer to support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of Ethernet and Wifi code readers on the market, though they tend to be targeted at industrial applications and usually cost more than the USB models.  The [company I work for](http://www.cognex.com/Main.aspx) makes such readers, and our fixed-mount DM200 reader is just such a device.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a small computer (or even a microcontroller) with RO media, USB, and networking capabilities plus a psu to turn any suitable scanner to a network one. Raspberry Pi, for example, could do it and seems to be hip these days.

Alternatively some portable devices (like Android tablets) could probably use a camera or even a USB scanner for scanning codes and come with capable networking features.